# Wordpress on nginx + Unbounce plugin popup 404

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404, unbounce

We are runnning a Wordpress web site on nginx + php-fpm7 on Ubuntu. We have problems with Unbounce plugin and their support cannot help. The plugin has a popup, which dynamically creates a page (.html) which loads inside the popup. Since this file physically doesn't exist the nginx returns a 404 (see screenshot). How can I configure the nginx to pass this request further to php-fpm?

[image]
This is my try_files directive in my nginx config:

```
location / 
{
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

My full nginx configuration is [here](https://jpst.it/19O50). Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?